# Disable Music Playing on terminated state in just_audio_background

Tags: flutter, dart, audio-player, just-audio

I am building a flutter music app and using just_audio & just_audio_background packages. I want music to be played only on foreground state not in terminated state. How can I achieve this? Currently music is playing in both states.

```
 final audio = AudioSource.uri(
        Uri.parse(audioModel.url),
        tag: MediaItem(
          id: audioModel.id.toString(),
          album: audioModel.album,
          title: audioModel.title,
          artUri: Uri.parse(
            audioModel.image.toString(),
          ),
        ),
      );
      _audioPlayer.setAudioSource(audio);
      _audioPlayer.play();
```

Comment: can you please share your file because you need to add didUpdateDipendency method and manage _audioPlayer variable according to lifecyle.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The official just_audio example demonstrates how to do this. i.e. From the just_audio page, click on "example", then notice that the following method is overridden in the widget:

```dart
  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    if (state == AppLifecycleState.paused) {
      // Release the player's resources when not in use. We use "stop" so that
      // if the app resumes later, it will still remember what position to
      // resume from.
      _player.stop();
    }
  }
```

Note that you can't directly override this method from your widget superclass, what you need to do is use the `WidgetsBindingObserver` mixin with your widget. The key line of code from the example is this:

```dart
class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
```

This adds the `didChangeAppLifecycleState` method which you can then override.